# Kubernetes IP service IP and ports

Tags: kubernetes

I've deployed a hello-world application on my Kubernetes cluster. When I access the app via `<cluster ip>:<port>` in my browser I get the following webpage: [hello-kuleuven app webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a4FN.png).

I understand that from outside the cluster you have to access the app via the cluster IP and the port specified in the deployment file (which in my case is 30001). From inside the cluster you have to contact the master node with its local IP and another port number, in my case `10.111.152.164:8080`.

My question is about the last line of the webpage:

```
Kubernetes listening in 443 available at tcp://10.96.0.1:443
```

Since, the service is already accessible from inside and outside the cluster by other ports and IP's, I'm not sure what this does.

Comment: Can you please point us to the app you are trying to deploy? It seem's it is  the address of Kubernetes API Server.

Comment: I'm deploying tutum/hello-world from Docker Hub. OK, but if that's the IP of the API Server, than the 10.111.152.164 (see webpage picture) is the IP of the service itself, right? Why do we need both?

Answer (score 1):

The IP `10.96.0.1` is a cluster IP of kube-dns service. You can see it using

```
kubectl get svc -n kube-apiserver
```

Kubernetes DNS schedules a DNS Pod and Service on the cluster, and configures the kubelets to tell individual containers to use the DNS Service’s IP to resolve DNS names.

So every pod you deploy uses kube-dns service (ClusterIP `10.96.0.1`) to resolve the dns names.

Read more about kube dns at kubernetes official document [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

Comment: Thanks, but I thought DNS was an optional feature? if that's the IP of the DNS service, what's the other internal IP than (10.111.152.164)?

Comment: DNS is an optional feature but when you deploy cluster using kubernetes the hard way, setting up everything manually. If you use any tool like kubeadm to deploy it comes for service discovery. It is an optional feature but also at the same time recommend way to do service discovery.  The IP 10.111.152.164 is the  clusterIP to your service it means that the xyz service will have same internal IP and all pods connected through that service can be accessed through that IP